# Download whole project from android developer?

Tags: android, download, android-actionbar

I want to use this project:

http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ActionBarCompat/index.html

How can I download all files at once?

Comment: The process should be documented on the sample itself, but alas it is not. I remember having this same problem, and having to dig around.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Go to Android SDK Manager in Eclispe
- Check Samples for SDK for the given API number
- Then install packages
- You will be able to find sample projects in your sdk folder

Answer (score 3):

The samples are downloadable with the AVD Manager tool, under the name "Samples for SDK API X".
You can get read this page for further explanation : http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/get.html.